# Generating dynamic reports in partner community with Custom URL field to pass the parameterrs

Tags: lightning, community, formula-field, urlhacking, parameters

We are facing a problem for passing dynamic filter values to reports from partner communities. We have tried all the combinations of pv0 and fv0. It is working fine in a full org but filters are not being applied when we are trying it from partner communities.

Note: I'm passing record Id to report when user clicks on custom formula field which has below formula.

HYPERLINK(

/* If they're in Lightning */
IF($User.UIThemeDisplayed="Theme4d",

/* Use Lightning syntax, optimized to avoid full page reload */
"#/sObject//view?fv0=",

/* Otherwise use Classic syntax */
"/?pv0=")

/* Append the Record ID */
&Id,

/* Specify the link text */
"Click here",

/* Keep it in the same browser tab to avoid full page reload */
"_self"
)
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't pass the  URL parameters in Lightning community.Please vote this idea

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TtzvQAC

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCJ2QAM